# Got a half mental breakdown because of vueJS

Tags: arrays, vue.js, sorting, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

Hey I am trying to fetch data from my Firestore database.
The problem is that vue does not want to logically coumpute my arrays and I do not see any sense in what I get as response from vue.

The code

```
const uid = store.state.user.uid;

var qry = maintainCollection.where('users', 'array-contains', uid)

const test = [];

qry.get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        test.push(doc.data())
    })
});

var sorted = test.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.deadline < b.deadline) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
});

console.log(sorted[0])
```

So now when I log sorted with an index of 0 I get undefined.
And also when I am trying to sort the array it simply does not work.

Comment: nothing to do with vue. promises are executed asynchronously, but your code assumes synchronous operations. move your code into after `snapshot.docs.forEach` in the `.then(snapshots` callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am very new to firebase and js in general :-)

Comment: Try to focus on JS basics before tackling a framework to not get overwhelmed by too much moving parts and have a solid knowledge base.